# Django illegal mix collations

Tags: python, mysql, django, mysql-python

When django tries to sync db with another external crm it raises the error:

```
OperationalError(1267, "Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='")
```

I tried to run

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE     utf8_general_ci;
```

No results. 
Also cnf file was created:

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8
[mysqld]
character_set_client=utf8
character_set_server=utf8
collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
```

And added to conf

```
  'OPTIONS': {
        'read_default_file': 'full path to cnf file'
    }
```

But it also hasn't results.